# Checking if an optional prop exists on my component in Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

My  component has the following prop, with `jsonpayload` being optional.

```
export interface props {
      jsonpayload?: payload[]
      onclick: () => void;
    }
```

Jest file:

```
const test_prop: dummy_props = {
    OnChange: jest.fn()
}

it("checks if jsonpayloadprop is present or not", () => {
        const demoComponent = enzyme.mount(<Demo {...dummy_props}/>);
        expect(demoComponent .props().JSONData.exists()).toEqual(false);
});
```

In my test I want to check if the `jsonpayload` prop is present or not. So far I've tried `exists()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably do

```js
expect(demoComponent.props().jsonpayload).toBeUndefined();
```

Also see [Truthiness](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/using-matchers.html#truthiness) in the jest docs.

But I really think that this test is not necessary at all. It basically tests that a prop that wasn't passed to a component is `undefined`. You can already expect react to handle that correctly.

Comment: oh no, there's more to the component. so if the `jsonpayload` is undefined i want to render something else instead.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty Okay but then you should instead test that the rendered output is the expected and call the test: `it('renders XY when no data is given)` or something similar.